# How do I delete every object that is checked

Tags: php, sql, forms, checkbox

Im kind of stuck. I want to be able to delete every user that is checked in the checkboxes.

This is my table/form right now **anvandare.php**:

```
   <?php

                        $query = "select * from user order by date DESC";

                        $run = $mysqli->query($query);

                  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){ //Hämtar informationen från användaren 

                        $userID = $row['userID'];
                        $email = $row['email'];
                        $company = $row['company'];
                        $fname = $row['fname'];
                        $tel = $row['tel'];
                        $test_status = $row['test_status'];
                        $date = $row['date'];

                  ?>
               <td><?php echo $userID; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $company; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $fname; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo zero($tel); ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $test_status; ?></td>
               <form action="delete.php" method="POST">
               <td><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $userID;?>" value="checked"></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Skicka"></form></td></tr>
         </table>
```

This is my **delete.php** right now..:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root", "");
mysql_select_db("Webbprojekt");

if(isset($_POST))
{
    var_dump($_POST);
}
?>
```

Do you have any successions of how to continue?
I get this when i submit:
[Three checked in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSUq2.png)

Comment: You seem to be using `mysqli` on one page and `mysql` on another, **don't do that** only use one, `mysqli`. as mysql is deprecated. With all that said, you have only made a check to see if `$_POST` `isset()` no attempt at deleting at all?

Comment: Thanks for fast response! I mad a delete-function before, but only for 1 object at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [foreach-loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach($_POST as $userID => $value){
    // use $userID to delete the database-entry here
}
```

If you change the name of your inputs to something like `userIds[<? echo $userID; ?>]` you will get the array `$_POST['userIds']` on the receiving page, which is useful if you want to add more inputs with additional information. This array can be used like above:

```
foreach($_POST['userIds'] as $userID => $value){
    // use $userID to delete the database-entry here
}
```